# X-cart PHP errors after server migration because register_long_arrays is off

Tags: php, .htaccess

We're moving a client site to a new server which has a very old install of X-Cart running on it. The X-cart shop is now throwing some output into the page stating that register_long_arrays is required and that it's not enabled.

We're running PHP 5.4.25 but I have no idea whether it's possible to re-enable 'register_long_arrays' and if so, how... I've tried a number of suggestions online such as adding 'php_flag register_long_arrays on' to .htaccess but with no luck... :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Best solution: upgrade x-cart. It is obviously obsolete and using functionality which NO LONGER EXISTS in recent PHP  versions. `register_long_arrays` was REMOVED from PHP in 5.4, so there is literally nothing you can do to get this going short of downgrading PHP or upgrading x-cart.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is exactly what I ended up doing. We're replacing X-cart with something else soon so as a temporary measure downgrading PHP solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgraded PHP as per Marc's comment as 5.4 removes all support for the register_long_arrays feature.